# How to pass data via STDIN from parent process to great grand child process (PIPES/FORK)

Tags: c++, process, pipe, fork

I have 4 processes. **Parent** -> **Process A (child of parent)** -> **Process B (child of process A)** -> **Process C (child of process B)**. **Parent** gets `stdin` from user, parses it and sends it as arguments to child **Process A** and executes a c++ program using `execv`. Then **process A** uses those arguments and outputs something to `stdout`. Using `pipes` and `dup2` **process A** send the `stdout` to `stdin` of a `python` script which is executed in **Process B**. Lastly, the `stdout` of process B is `stdin` of another C++ program in **Process C**.

Now, the program that runs in **Process C** also needs to take in `stdin` input (as in when the user types it in terminal`. However, I am not able to send those commands to Process C from the parent process. The input command just gets in to the parent, and the parent is basically sending what it correctly parses to process A via pipe.

The Parent process is getting the stdin like so and the parses the string and sends it to child:

```
//parent process
Parser P;
while (!std::cin.eof()) {
             std::string line;
             std::getline(std::cin, line);

       arguments = P.BeginParsing(line);
              if (arguments.size() > 0) {
                  for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                      finalArguments[k] = arguments[k];
                  }
                  
                  close(fd[0]);
                  write(fd[1],finalArguments,4*sizeof(int));
                  close(fd[1]);
              }
 }
```

How do we send data from Parent stdin to great grand child basically, while the great grand child gets stdin from it's parent. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you use named pipes (fifo) in a shell for this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Comment: Actually, they all share the same stdin, You just need to end the while loop after what you want to parse in the parent process, rather than read till eof.